# I want to fetch my Test Flight User's Apple id from TestFlight Programatically in the application

Tags: ios, testflight

I want to enable a certain feature for some of my  Internal and external users in the Test Flight using my application. Is there a way I can fetch his details or id programatically in my code?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't get read email addresses programmatically from Swift. TestFlight is only a distribution channel, it doesn't offer any extra functionality from the code side.

To enable something specific for specific users, you would either need to:

- Produce a special build, make an internal/external group for the specific people manually, and only give that group access to the given build
- As part of your app, ask users to login, and control the functionality by some server side value/config